# SUM() not working on Google script function cell value in Google Sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet like

[image]

The Columns are like
Dimension: **C**
Calculated Area: **D**
Total Area: **E**

The user has to enter **Dimensions** and the **Calculated Area** is auto filled by the calculated area using a custom Google Sheet function which returns float number.

```
=areaInchToFoot(C9)
```

**Total Area** field calculates sum of the fields of **Calculated Area** thus the formula used is

```
=SUM(D9:D15)
```

But it gives only **0** in the sum field.

Comment: Can you provide the script of ``areaInchToFoot()``? Because I thought that from your image, the values calculated by ``areaInchToFoot()`` might be put as the string type. If the values are the string type, the result by ``SUM()`` becomes ``0``. So can I confirm about this?

Comment: Sometimes just doing a *1 as the last operation is sufficient ie "=areaInchToFoot(C9)*1"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with inbuilt functions:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROUND(CONVERT(INDEX(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(,"Select "&join(",",REGEXREPLACE(A2:A6,"(\d+)""\s+x\s+(\d+)""","$1*$2")))),,2),"in^2","ft^2"),2))
```

- REGEX to REPLACE `x` to `*` and remove `"`(114*121)
- JOIN the array using `,`(114*121,46*21,..)
- QUERY to evaluate each of those strings
- INDEX/TRANSPOSE to remove query's headers and transpose columns to rows
- CONVERT to convert inch<sup>2</sup> to ft<sup>2</sup>
- ROUND it to 2 decimals.
- SUM up, if needed.